# cUrl - captive portal - HTTP 200 OK, but Location header redirect

Tags: http, curl, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I'm trying to log into a HTTP based captive portal using cUrl.
As soon as I send a request I get the following back:

```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Location:
> Location: https://somewebsite:someport/portal/gateway?sessionId=someid&portal=someportal&action=cwa&token=sometoken
```

I would really like to follow the Location header, however, since the status code is 200 cUrl is not following the redirect even if I use the -L option. (I'm well aware of the fact that the status code for a redirect should not be 200, but it's not a portal that's under my control, so I can't change it.)

So the next thing I tried was to parse the location header from the response and query a cUrl to it, like so:

```
cUrl -sS -v https://somewebsite:someport/portal/gateway?sessionId=someid&portal=someportal&action=cwa&token=sometoken`
```

However, this returns the following output (masked with <>):

```
*   Trying <someip>...                                                                                                                                                                 [308/1885]
* Local Interface wlan0 is ip <someip> using address family 2
* Local port: 0
* Connected to <somehost> (<someip>) port <someport> (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 707 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.0 / RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: <somename> (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: <somesubject>
*        start date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 09:59:25 GMT
*        expire date: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 23:59:00 GMT
*        issuer: <someissuer>
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> GET <urlwithouthost> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <host>:<port>
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<notSameIdAsInUrl>; Path=/portal/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2017 10:00:27 GMT
< Server: server
< 
...
```

if anyone knows why I constantly get "not Found", even if I just follow the redirect, I'd really appreciate any suggestion to solve this.

Greetings,
Lars

Comment: They might detect you're not a browser, try setting `User-Agent:` etc to fly more under the radar. And use your browsers' devtools to see what requests they send and compare to your curl request.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thank you so much! Would have took me days to figure that out on my own :)